# How to render multiple items from an API call using React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am using `axios` to get the data from an API. My component has an `articles` array in the `state` which is where the data from the API request will go.

I am still really new to React and trying to find information on displaying multiple articles on the page. That is what I am trying to figure out. Maybe I am using `this.state` wrong?

I've also tried `fetch()` then using a `.then()` to return the information. Neither way has helped me achieve what I am trying to display:

```
import React from "react";
import axios from "axios";

class Pages extends React.Component{

    constructor(){
        super();
        this.state = {
            articles : []
        }
    }

    componentDidMount(){
        this.getArticles().then(res =>
            {
                console.log(res);
                this.setState({articles : res.data.articles});
            });
    }

    getArticles(){
        return axios.get('https://newsapi.org/v2/everything?domains=wsj.com,nytimes.com&apiKey=API_KEY');
     };

      render(){
        return (
            <div className="ui raised very padded text container segment">
        <p>
        Yo!

         {this.state.articles[0] ? this.state.articles[0].author : ''}

        </p>

        </div>
        );

      }

}


export default Pages;
```

In the return section I want to display the article name, author, url link, and the content of the article.

Comment: log and comment `res.data.articles` value here.
also dont add api key on public. just add some dummy text there

Comment: So take out the this.state? and do res.data.articles[0], res.data.articles[0].title etc

Comment: console.log(res);

what is this logged result?

Comment: i think now u can see only one elemnt to dom and if u want to see multiple elements you need to use map function

Comment: check with @Dacre Denny answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you're wanting to render all articles that are available after your `axios` request completes.

To achieve that, consider using the `map()` method on the `state.articles` array. This allows you to "map" each item from the raw document JSON data to an `<li>` element containing the article information that you want to display to your users.

When rendering each `<li>`, you can access the content of the current `article` being mapped, to render that into the components overall rendered result:

```
  render(){
    return (
        <div className="ui raised very padded text container segment">

        <ul>
            { this.state.articles.map((article, index) => {
               return (<li key={index}>
                <h2>{ article.name }</h2>
                <div>{ article.author }</div>
                <p>{ article.content }</p>
                <a href={article.url}>{ article.url }</a>
               </li> )
            })}
        </ul>
    <p>Yo!</p>
    </div>
    );
  }
```

Something also to note is that, when rendering lists in React, you [should include a unique `key` for each list item](https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html#keys) rendered (in the code above, the `key` is specified as the index of the `article` being mapped).

#### Update

To render the first article only (if present) while retaining your component's current state structure, you could `slice()` the `articles` array before performing the `map()`. This would cause a new array (with only the first article) to be passed to `map()` - the end result being that  only the first article is rendered:

```
{ this.state.articles.slice(0,1).map((article, index) => {
  /* Existing code from answer */
}}
```

Comment: Omg YES you are a wizard. Though I did not need all the articles I only needed one thats why I had article[0]. Where in .map would I filter it to pull from the 1st array in the API?

Comment: Glad I could help! Just updated answer - does that help?

Comment: OMG YES! Ive been trying some many different things before I asked for help. GENIUS! THANK YOU THANK YOU!

Comment: Heh you're totally welcome - all the best with your project :-)

Comment: Got it no problem